# Python dictionary formatting "if"

Tags: python, dictionary

here is my code :

```
while True:
    event = recieve_json_response(ws)

    try:
        if event['d']['guild_id'] == "699288260479942686" and event['d']['channel_id'] == "831878180586389514":
            content = event['d']
            print(f"{content}")
        op_code = event('op')
        if op_code == 11:
            print('heartbeat received')
    except:
        pass
```

how can i add a var to this "if" part that prints the content var only if in event, a certain var contains a certain word

```
if event['d']['guild_id'] == "699288260479942686" and event['d']['channel_id'] == "831878180586389514":
```

here is the whole event dictionary :

```
d = {
    "embeds": [
        {
            "type": "rich",
            "timestamp": "2022-06-26T17:01:21.432000+00:00",
            "footer": {"text": "© XkijuX & Co"},
            "fields": [
                {
                    "value": "+ `130` :gold:\n+ `65` :diamond:\n+ `55` :obsidian:\n\n:blank::blank::blank::blank::blank::blank::blank::blank:",
                    "name": "**During the session you found:**",
                    "inline": True,
                },
                {
                    "value": ":diamond: → `15370` durability left.",
                    "name": "**Your Pickaxe:**",
                    "inline": True,
                },
            ],
            "color": 32952,
            "author": {
                "proxy_icon_url": "https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/c07-xyFM1v0DMWTunoCcOYoM-TQ02lkVONCAtmXLrko/https/cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/319534390461988866/44f0274292e7954e1ddc7d759d6f1e89.webp",
                "name": "arsene#8880",
                "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/319534390461988866/44f0274292e7954e1ddc7d759d6f1e89.webp",
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to make the code do like :

if this

```
event['d']['embeds'][0]['fields'][0]['name']
```

name var contains the word "session", event is printed

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` keyword.

For example:

```
if "session" in event['d']['embeds'][0]['fields'][0]['name']:
    # do something
```